# Autopopulating a column with a Trigger SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, triggers

I'm trying to start a sequence that automatically populates a column when an insertion has been made. It should start from 500 and increment by 1. Any idea how would I go about doing this? So far I have something like this, but it seems to crash

```
CREATE TRIGGER ADD_TRIGGER ON tablename
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    ADD colname NUMBER IDENTITY(500,1);
END
GO
```

Comment: Upgrade to Oracle 12.1+ and use `identity`.

Comment: See [**Auto-increment primary key in Pre 12c releases (Identity functionality**)](http://lalitkumarb.com/2015/01/20/auto-increment-primary-key-in-pre-12c-releases-identity-functionality/) and [**IDENTITY column autoincrement functionality in Oracle 12c**](http://lalitkumarb.com/2015/01/20/identity-column-autoincrement-functionality-in-oracle-12c/).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a sequence

```
CREATE SEQUENCE mySeq
  START WITH 500
  INCREMENT BY 1
  CACHE 100;
```

and then use it in your trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER myTrigger
  AFTER INSERT ON table_name
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT mySeq.nextval
    INTO :new.colname 
    FROM dual;
END;
```

Comment: What is dual? and what is CACHE?

Comment: dual is a special table: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries009.htm  The cache option is used to 'pre-assign' values in blocks. If sequences 1-10 were issued and the database crashed the nextval would be 101. This caching will vary in size depending upon your use, however the more simultaneous transactions you anticipate the larger this should be.

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle 12c** introduces [**IDENTITY COLUMNS**](http://lalitkumarb.com/2015/01/20/identity-column-autoincrement-functionality-in-oracle-12c/).

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE new_identity_table
  2    (
  3      ID   NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  4      text VARCHAR2(50)
  5    );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> INSERT
  2  INTO new_identity_table
  3    (
  4      text
  5    )
  6    VALUES
  7    (
  8      'This table has an identity column'
  9    );

1 row created.

SQL> column text format A40;
SQL>
SQL> select * from new_identity_table;

        ID TEXT
---------- ----------------------------------------
         1 This table has an identity column
```

Oracle creates a `sequence` to populate the `identity column`. You can find it named as `ISEQ$$`

```
SQL> select sequence_name, min_value, max_value, increment_by from user_sequences;

SEQUENCE_NAME         MIN_VALUE  MAX_VALUE                     INCREMENT_BY
-------------------- ---------- ----------------------------   ------------
ISEQ$$_93199                  1 9999999999999999999999999999   1
```

More more information about the identity columns, use the `ALL_TAB_IDENTITY_COLS` view.

```
SQL> SELECT table_name,
  2         column_name,
  3         generation_type,
  4         identity_options
  5  FROM   all_tab_identity_cols
  6  WHERE  owner = 'LALIT'
  7  ORDER BY 1, 2;

TABLE_NAME           COLUMN_NAME     GENERATION IDENTITY_OPTIONS
-------------------- --------------- ---------- --------------------------------------------------
NEW_IDENTITY_TABLE   ID              ALWAYS     START WITH: 1, INCREMENT BY: 1, MAX_VALUE: 9999999
                                                999999999999999999999, MIN_VALUE: 1, CYCLE_FLAG: N
                                                , CACHE_SIZE: 20, ORDER_FLAG: N
```

For pre 12c releases, see [**Auto-increment primary key in Pre 12c releases (Identity functionality)**](http://lalitkumarb.com/2015/01/20/auto-increment-primary-key-in-pre-12c-releases-identity-functionality/)